# Hosting an ASP.NET MVC site in a webhotel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ftp, host

We are a group of students trying to host our project website in a webhotel, using a test server environment, before we decide to publish it.

However we are having trouble correctly publishing it to this environemnt, and have not been able to get help from the host support.

This is the folder structure for the test environment:
https://puu.sh/sP8Dq/b022c83f34.png

This is the folder structure for our project in Visual Studio:
https://puu.sh/sP8Gb/24e85dfff6.png

When we use FTP to upload our project into the httpdocs folder, along with the web.config, the site remains in the default state.

This is how the ftp server looks like:
https://puu.sh/sP8PE/26e3e45f4a.png

This is a first for us, so any help in how to host our site would be appreciated.

Comment: what is your host? is it plesk ?

Comment: Yes, it is plesk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should be sure that your host provides the necessary tools to host a asp.net mvc application you need to ask this from your host provider, tell them what version of MVC your application is made of, and if its possible to host it there, there are afew issues with lower versions of plesk.
as what you have to do so your website comes up :

you have to copy the whole mvc project into httpdocs folder to view it online.

You need to ensure you are copying your websites 'bin' folder. You may also need to ensure that the MVC assemblies are in it.

When you installed MVC on your local machine several assemblies are registered with the GAC. It may be that your host does not have all the required ASP.NET MVC assemblies installed; if not then you will see a configuration error.

As these assemblies are registered in the GAC, the bin folder will not contain them by default.

Make sure your project explicitly references the following DLLs and make sure the Copy Local property is true.

- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor
- Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure

Rebuild your project and check the bin folder. These files should now be present. Upload the contents of this folder to your host.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have uploaded the project folder, along with the bin folder and have made sure all the mentioned assemblies are present, but the site looks the same as before. There is an index.html file present in the httpdocs be default, which is what is shown in the site URL. Support mentioned changing the the default index page in the web.config, but I haven't been able to find anything of the sort in there. I am unsure whether the host supports our version of MVC, i will try and contact them about that.

Comment: delete the default html file, go to IIS options in your plesk control panel, change its index orders, What is the first thing you want to be loaded on your website?

Comment: Plesk >> Websites & Domains >> Show Advanced Options >> Virtual Directories >> Directory Properties >> Click on the desired page and click on Up under "Default documents search order" >> Click Ok

Comment: I can't seem to find the IIS options in the control panel and there is no option to show advanced options. Perhaps it is an outdated version? https://puu.sh/sPb9t/4648cab6b7.png

Comment: Then Contact Your Host Provider and ask them to do it manually tell them you want to have `certain` view as your default page, they'll do it using IIS its self. if they couldn't help you i suggest you find more suitable host provider like godaddy or bluehost or etc.. be sure to ask for windows host not Linux.

Comment: @user1696992 godaddy offers Parallels Plesk Panel,

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give those hosts a try.